# Coefficients of a certain polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Could you help me to solve this?

Let $$P=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$$ a complex polynomial and $M$ a positive real number such that for all $z$ in the unit circle, $M$ is greater then $|P(z)|$.

Prove that for all $k \in \{0,\ldots,n\}, M$ is greater than $a_k$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using both sides of the triangular identity in vain, or inputting in the polynomial particular values that cancels some terms but it doesn’t seem to work...